# How to use dll in classic asp

Tags: dll, vbscript, asp-classic

I asked a server if they could install aspJpeg so I can use it in my classic asp project but they told me that I should put its DLL in my own bin folder.

I have read some answers and guidelines using Visual Studio . But I didn't use visual studio in my project. There is no bin folder and no more extra files and settings to add and consume a dll in my project.

Can I consume a dll using  manual code through web.config or inline with my asp codes (or vbscript code) or something like that? I have no access to command prompt and server administration and I want to do that through pure coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DLL must be registered on server side by using command

```
regsvr32 <youdll>
```

Your hosting company/hosting support team have to do this. You cannot do this remotely.

By the way, what IIS version are you using?

> *"There is no bin folder"*

Yes, because it's not an ASP.NET project.

> *"but they told me that I should put its DLL in my own bin folder."*

When you contacted hosting support team, did you mentioned that you are running Classic ASP website? You could upload DLL, but you cannot register it on their server.

Comment: Thank you. Is there difference between classic or .net? Can dot net consume a dll by its own without registering on the server?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Yes, Classic ASP *(VBScript by extension)* uses DLLs that are exposed to COM, these DLLs have to be registered in the registry of the server where the website is hosted there is no way around it. As Zam has already mentioned this has to be done by someone with access to the server, i.e the Hosting Company. ASP.Net is compiled code *(basically you end up with a DLL)* and all references to the project can be stored in the `bin` folder. They can also use the GAC on the server but this requires them to be signed and registered with the GAC.